# How to increase lighthouse timeout for slow pages

Tags: javascript, accessibility, lighthouse

I'm using lighthouse version 2 for accessibility testing on a webapp. Some of the pages of this app are too slow to load (take couple of dozen of seconds.

When running lighthouse against those pages, it seems lighthouse does not load the page entirely, but times-out in 10s. When looking into lighthouse code base I found that the timeout is hard coded in a variable and this cannot be overridden by a config as it's defined like this:

[const CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 10000;](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/branch2.x/lighthouse-core/gather/connections/cri.js#L15)

This is how I'm trying to load lighthose

```js
var lighthouse = require('lighthouse');
var chromeLauncher = require('lighthouse/chrome-launcher/chrome-launcher');
var ReportGenerator = require('lighthouse/lighthouse-core/report/v2/report-generator')

var url = 'http://localhost:8080/myApp/slowpage';
var flags = {
  output: 'json',
  port: 57387,
  disableStorageReset: true
}

var config = {
  extends: 'lighthouse:default',
  settings: {
    onlyCategories: [
      'accessibility',
      'best-practices',
    ],
  }
}

lighthouse(url, flags, config).then(function(results) {
  return results;
}).then(function(results) { 
  html = new ReportGenerator().generateReportHtml(results);
  console.log(html);
}).catch(error => { console.log('caught', error.message); });
```

Is there a way to increase the timeout?

Comment: ended up here in 2022, without any answers lol